# How to post checked radio buttons

Tags: php, javascript, post

i have a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fPtMq/31/). What it does is that when the user clicks on the "Add Question" button, it adds a radio buttons in each row. But what I want to do is use $_POST to post selected radio buttons in each row into the the insertQuestions.php page (action the form takes use to).

So what I want to know is how do I write the $_POST statement to be able to paste checked radio buttons?

UPDATE:

Is this code below correct in terms of finding the ReplyId for the selected radio by using z case statement then a query:

```
$i = 0;
$c = count($_POST['reply']);

$insertquestion = array();

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){

    switch ($_POST['reply'][$i]){

    case "Single": 
    $selected_option = "Single";
    break;

    case "Multiple": 
    $selected_option = "Multiple";
    break;

    default:
    $selected_option = "";
    break;

    }      


    $replyquery = "SELECT ReplyId FROM Reply WHERE (ReplyType = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply'])."')";
    $replyrs = mysql_query($replyquery);
    $replyrecord = mysql_fetch_array($replyrs);
    $replyid = $replyrecord['ReplyId'];
```

Comment: Do you mean that you have a process page and you want to send user selection to this process page using $_POST? php is server side script it cannot do that, you will have to use ajax or jQuery post method.

Comment: @anuragsn7 No I am not saying that,  Ialready have AJAX and all that set up, all I want to know is what is the correct name attribute to $_POST a checked radio button i.e $_POST[...]?

Comment: @user1304328 Same as any form input, you match the `$_POST` index to the `name=""` attribute.

Comment: @user1304328 See my latest comment in my answer for update to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is when you run your AJAX script.  On the process page you would use something like

```
<?PHP
$reply1 = $_POST['reply1'];
$reply2 = $_POST['reply2'];
```

<strike>however you will want to change the name of the input fields to `name="reply[]"` which will make the posted data an array</strike>

UPDATE:
The previous is only valid for checkboxes in this case (which there are none)  With checkboxes of the same name,  is checkbox 1 is checked and then checkbox 2 is checked, you will only get the value of checkbox 2 on the post.

Since reply is the name with a number after for duplicated questions, you can always get all posted variables by just using `$_POST`.  Doing this will give you an array of ALL posted data

If you want to go through each reply since it is dynamic just do a foreach statement

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) {
    //Run script to process each posted reply 
}
```

Comment: when you said put name as an [] array, it that only for the radio buttons in the form or for the appended radio buttons as well?

Comment: Im sorry.. this method really only applies to checkboxes.   If you have a multiple checkboxes that have the same name, you will want to make it an array.  If you dont, checkboxes will overwrite the previously checked.   What you have is fine in the fiddle,  Because you are using a different name for each set of questions (reply, reply1, reply2 and so on)

Comment: you would do  $_POST['reply1'] to get the reply to answer 1, $_POST['reply2'] to get the reply to answer 2 and so on.  Also see the edit of the foreach to go through each answer since you can add many questions

Comment: One final question, I am creating a query to find all the ReplyId's for the selected radio button. In other wordss if 'Single' radio button is selected, it will look up 'Single' in the 'ReplyType' field in database, if selected radio button is 'Multiple' then do same thing but look up 'Multiple'. Is the above code correct to do this? Thought I will ask an expert first like yourself :)

Comment: If I understand your question, then yes.  If you try it out and have some issues, just post the new question here and the community can help after seeing your examples of what you have done with that.

Comment: @user1304328:  Sorry... you code is close to correct.  You will need to take my advice in the making the name return an array.  instead of `name="reply"+count` you will want to do `name="reply["+count+"]` to make your code work correctly.  Disclaimer: this is not tested so there may be some other errors.